# NextJS authenticated redirect HOC / React Hook

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
// TODO: use React Custom Hook or HOC to make authenticatedRedirect reusable
  const { status } = useSession();
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "authenticated") {
      setTimeout(() => {
        router.push("/dashboard");
      }, 1500);
    }
  }, [status, router]);
```

I found out I have to use this component in a lot of pages. The use of this component is to redirect user if they are "authenticated".

I wonder if this is achievable in React hook?

Comment: I assume `useSession` already updates the `status` when user is authenticated. Therefore your `useEffect` will trigger. Why bother using `setTimeout`?

Comment: I was just following an example tutorial. but I would mainly want to focus on how to make it resusable. :)

Comment: Yes, this could be moved into a React hook or wrapped in a HOC. What have you tried and what issue are you facing?